# Perl or Sed command to delete content before matching expression

Tags: regex, perl, sed, expression

I have a directory of html files in which I'd like to remove all content (and including) a matched expression.  I have tried this (where XXXXXX    us the string I am looking for:

```
perl -pi -e "$a++if s/.*XXXXXX.*//si;$a||s/.*//s" *.html
```

I am getting this error (where when I press enter, it is changing my command, see first line):

```
perl -pi -e "$a=1 if *.htmla && s/.*XXXXXX.*//is; s/.*//s if *.htmla" *.html
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "*.htmla"
    (Missing operator before htmla?)
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "*.htmla"
    (Missing operator before htmla?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "="
syntax error at -e line 1, near "*.htmla
"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Any help on Perl command to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
'
```

instead  of

```
"
```

otherwise your shell will expand $a.

```
perl -pi -e "$a++if s/.*XXXXXX.*//si;$a||s/.*//s" *.html
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all lines up to a line, which matches some regular expression.

You can give a range to sed and delete from the first line until and including the match

```
sed -i -e '1,/match/d' file.html
```

If you want to remove the content from every line, which matches a regular expression

```
sed -i -e 's/.*match//' file.html
```

Comment: Expect the expression in the second `sed` command should have a .* following the "match" e.g., `sed 's/^.*match.*$//' file.html > file.bak`, review the results and then rename file.bak to overwrite file.html

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps This would clear the whole line then. Editing in place is done through the `-i` option. If you need a backup file, use `-i.bak` instead.

Comment: That's right -- it would *clear* (i.e., empty) the line, but not delete it.  I assumed that is what you meant by "*remove the content from every line, which matches a regular expression*" as opposed to "... delete ...".  Also, per the OP, having the .* before and after seems to be what he wants.  I am aware of what the `-i` option does; I just personally discourage it; YMMV.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps Since OP hasn't commented on anything, I don't know what s/he really wants.

Answer (score 0):

Quite with  `'` instead of `"`.

Variables are interpolated in  `"`-quoted material; shells do this and so does Perl.

In this case, your shell which will substitute `$a` with its value before feeding the result to Perl.
The result is illegal Perl syntax.